# Cloud Functions - OpenCV Videocapture Read method fails for larger files from cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, function, opencv, cloud

I created a cloud function to read a video file from cloud storage and read frames and create an image for each frame.
This function works for small files which is 1-2 MB, However, this method fails while reading larger file 130 MB.

```
import cv2
from google.cloud import storage

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucker_name]/[filename.mp4]")

if vidcap.isOpened():    
    vidcap.open("https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucker_name]/[filename.mp4]")
success,image = vidcap.read()
print(success)
```

Expected the print will return true and an image will hold an image of a first frame.

Comment: What is your question? So far this reads more like a bug report that should have been posted to the OpenCV issue tracker...